# Cohomology of the affine singular and projective smooth model

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, algebraic-curves

In the literature, in many places the computations of Cohomology
of the affine singular and projective smooth models are done
interchangeably. Let us work with curves. For example, if $\pi:Y\to \mathbb{P}^{1}$ is a cyclic cover of the $\mathbb{P}^{1}$, then $Y$ is projective and smooth but in  in practical cohomological computations the affine singular model $X$ defined by the equation $X:=\{y^l=\prod
(x-a_k)^{d_k}\}$ is used. Of course $Y$ is the normalization of
$X$ and I know that $H^1(Y,\mathcal{O}_{Y})\cong H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$. But for example when the curve is defined over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$ and you compute the
Hasse-Witt matrix $F:H^1(Y,\mathcal{O}_{Y})\to
H^1(Y,\mathcal{O}_{Y})$ how can one still use the basis of
$H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$ and computations be in terms of $a_k$ and
$d_k$ above (which come from $X$)?

The precise example that I have in mind is the following: (Taken
from the paper I. Bouw, The p-rank of ramified covers of curves.
Compositio Math. 126 (2001), 295–322.). The standard way of
computing the above Hasse-Witt matrix is to decompose the
cohomology $H^1(Y,\mathcal{O}_{Y})$ in to eigenspaces
$H^1(Y,\mathcal{O}_{Y})_{i}$ of the natural $\mathbb{Z}/l
\mathbb{Z}$-action for $1\leq i\leq l-1$. Then a basis for $H^1(Y,\mathcal{O}_{Y})_{i}$
is computed by taking two open sets
$V_1=\pi^{-1}(\mathbb{P}^{1}\setminus \infty)$ and
$V_2=\pi^{-1}(\mathbb{P}^{1}\setminus \{0\})$. Then
$\Gamma(V_1,\mathcal{O}_{V_1})=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{l-1} k[x]v_i$
where $v_i=y^i \prod (x-a_k)^{-[id_k/l]}$. My problem/question is:
$v_i$ is only a rational section (not regular) and on $X$ (not $Y$) so
how can it be viewed as a regular section? If you pull it back to
$Y$ to become a regular function, then first of all the equation
of $v_i$ certainly changes and secondly, how come that the
resulting matrix $F$ is still the same, although we are using a
basis of $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$ (instead of
$H^1(Y,\mathcal{O}_{Y})$)? (Because if $F:V\to V$ and you change
the basis, of course the matrix of $F$ changes too!)